# (How) can I access struts action fields directly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, struts2

I used hidden variables to achieve this before. But I wanted to remove the hidden variables for security reasons and hence I have to be able to access the action fields without using hidden fields. How can I do that?

Comment: what you mean by any of the from elements?

Comment: hidden fields or any other html controls

Comment: If your goal is *security*, hopefully it's obvious the accepted answer does zero to address that.

Comment: Would like to hear more about that Dave Newton . All I was thinking was that hidden values are very easy to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the js variables using the action fields like -

```
<script>
var item = '<s:property value="item" />';
....
</script>
```

where the Action class has a `getItem()` method.

Comment: With the caveat that it should be JavaScript-escaped; `<s:property value="item" escapeJavaScript="true"/>`